# Application crashes in loading C++ jni library dynamically linked with openss-1.0.1h

Tags: android, openssl, dynamic-linking

I am using a C++ library. Which is dynamically linked with OpenSSL-1.0.1 h libraries(i.e libssl.so, libcrypto.so) and the OpenSSL libraries are pre-built. The problem is when I try to load the library using my android application, application crashes. And in log cat, I can see the reason something like this -

"could not find libssl.so.1.0.0 needed by libABC.so"

I haven't called system.loadlibrary() for OpenSSL libraries, I only called that for my C++ library.

This issue never works when I use the dynamic linking of OpenSSL-1.0.0 or static linking of OpenSSL-1.0.1h.

I don't know how to resolve the issue. Can anyone help me with this?

I did the following to load library -

```
System.loadLibrary("ssl");
System.loadLibrary("crypto");
System.loadLibrary("ABC");
```

Comment: So call System.loadlibrary for libssl. That's what you're supposed to do.

Comment: but previously I never called System.loadlibrary for libssl and it worked with openssl-1.0.0

Comment: Probably luck, the system may preload libssl. You are supposed to manually load any dependencies using System.load library.

Comment: May be. Just now I have called system.loadlibrary("libssl.so") but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have two problems. First is linking against OpenSSL; and second is actually finding the library in the APK.

---

> I am using a C++ library, which is dynamically linked with openss-1.0.1 h libraries...

Here is your first problem. Android's equivalent of `init` is `zygote`. Zygote loads the platform's version of OpenSSL. When Zygote forks to start your app, you app gets the already linked version of OpenSSL, which is likely 0.9.8. Since your app is built against 1.0.1, you will crash at runtime because 0.9.8 and 1.0.0 are *not* binary compatible.

To resolve this, you have to build a wrapper shared object that links against the *static* version of the OpenSSL library. Then, when you need to make an OpenSSL call, you expose it through your wrapper. For example, you might have a `GetSslContext` that wraps the calls to OpenSSL's `SSLv23_method`, `SSL_CTX_new`, `SSL_CTX_set_options`, etc.

This avoids calling into Zygote's downlevel OpenSSL. Its also documented on the OpenSSL wiki at [OpenSSL and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android#Miscellaneous).

---

> "could not find libssl.so.1.0.0 needed by libABC.so"

Here is your second problem. First, create a wrapper shared object as described above. Second, place your shared objects in the proper directory. The shared wrapper should be placed in the `lib/` directory. I believe you can also have specialized versions of the library in subdirectories. For example, `lib/` would be a generic fallback, while `lib/armv7-a/` would be a shared object built specifically for ARMv7a.

You can find the libraries at runtime with the [ApplicationInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html) class and its [nativeLibDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#nativeLibraryDir) method:

```
public String nativeLibraryDir

    Full path to the directory where native JNI libraries are stored.
```

Also see Android's [JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) and the Native Libraries section.

---

```
 System.loadLibrary("ssl");
 System.loadLibrary("crypto");
```

Related, `libssl` depends upon `libcrypto`, so it should be:

```
 static {
     System.loadLibrary("crypto");
     System.loadLibrary("ssl");
 }
```

But you should probably avoid it and use a wrapper shared object.

Comment: Can you please refer me a link where I can found sufficient references for creating wrappers for openssl?

Comment: @naseef - Here's what I used when learning it: [Android Native Development Kit Cookbook](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1849691509). You can find sample chapters online from Packet Publishing. Luckily, they offer Chapter 8 and Chapter 9, which are the chapters you need.

Comment: I am summarizing what I understood, I will create a wrapper library that will contain the functionalities of openssl-1.0.1h library wrapped. Secondly I will load the native library. Does calling System.loadlibrary("ABC") will put the library on /lib directory? This point is not clear to me. Can you please clarify?